# xfce does not start (X.Org X server: no screens found)

Tags: 14.04, xorg, xfce, chromebook

```
chronos@localhost / $ sudo startxfce4
Entering /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
/usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X server

_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root

X.Org X Server 1.11.3
Release Date: 2011-12-16
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.42-61-generic x86_64 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux localhost 3.8.11 #1 SMP Wed Jan 6 20:08:04 PST 2016 x86_64
Kernel command line: cros_secure  console= loglevel=7 init=/sbin/init cros_secure oops=panic panic=-1 root=/dev/dm-0 rootwait ro dm_verity.error_behavior=3 dm_verity.max_bios=-1 dm_verity.dev_wait=1 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 2506752 verity payload=PARTUUID=a8b78ac0-ef8c-6741-bb17-0295217c31ca/PARTNROFF=1 hashtree=PARTUUID=a8b78ac0-ef8c-6741-bb17-0295217c31ca/PARTNROFF=1 hashstart=2506752 alg=sha1 root_hexdigest=19995d817803b16bfec145455cc381a345919bcd salt=badac15c3bac941e59744e3d2bd1693a45bd3f9ac7daaae970a32aa81be7a25f" noinitrd vt.global_cursor_default=0 kern_guid=a8b78ac0-ef8c-6741-bb17-0295217c31ca add_efi_memmap boot=local noresume noswap i915.modeset=1 tpm_tis.force=1 tpm_tis.interrupts=0 nmi_watchdog=panic,lapic iTCO_vendor_support.vendorsupport=3  
Build Date: 12 February 2015  02:49:01PM
xorg-server 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.17 (For technical support please see http://ww w.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.30.2
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(++) Log file: "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log", Time: Fri Jan 22 15:01:37 2016
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/tmp/Xorg.crouton.1.log" for additional information.

 ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
/usr/bin/xinit: giving up
/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/xinit: server error
Unmounting /mnt/stateful_partition/crouton/chroots/precise...
```

this is what it says can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

never mind!

i figured it out ^_^

i typed in

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -u
```

and it updated and its now fixed

Comment: Please accept your answer by clicking the check mark beside it.